# Office.Recipients (interface) getAsync: In OWA, the To field is not resolved after losing the field focus

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

The "getAsync" function of the office recipient interface returns resolved recipients.

- [Unresolved Recipient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfqPh.png)
- [Resolved Recipient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYSdR.png)

In case a recipient is not resolved, this recipient won't be returned by this function.

We find a way/**bug** how to add a recipient that won't be properly resolved.

In case an outlook user enter an email address (without clicking on the outlook recipient proposals, without pressing tab/space or ";") and then click on another field (change field focus), for example by pressing on the messsage body, the content of the To field is not resolved.

In case the field focus is lost, the content of the fields should be resolved.

We have tested this behaviour with the Script Lab Add-in and we could confirm the issue.

- [Script Lab Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2L2hK.png)

In addition, we could notice that if we set a new recipient using the setAsync or addAsync method, the start content of the to field is not resolved, only the new added email adress is validated.

- [Script Lab after setAsync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN96H.png)

**Our suggestions:**

- The set method should remove the start content or resolved the start
  email address also.
- The main issue is the missing "resolve" on field focus lost.

**Our question:**

- Why the field is not resolved after field focus change?
- How is it possible to get the recipient value in this specific case ?

Comment: I'd suggest posting this as an issue to the `Office-JS` repo in github.

Comment: Issue has been created. https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/2569